# Django request timeout for some static files when running manage.py test package.to.unit.test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, request, timeout

**Context**:

We run Cypress tests which use instances of our application started using `manage.py test package.test.suite`. The test fixtures and environment are all set up using a class extended from `django.contrib.staticfiles.testing.StaticLiveServerTestCase`. A unit test/method is added to the extended class which invokes Cypress as a subprocess to run the tests and asserts against the exit code of the subprocess.

Versions:

- Python: 3.6.8
- Django: 2.2.3
- macOS: Mojave 10.14.6

**The problem**:

This worked well until yesterday when I updated Cypress via npm. Now when I start a server using `manage.py test some.test.suite` the server will fail to serve all of the static resources requested by the browser. Specifically, it almost always fails to serve some .woff fonts and a random javascript/css file or two. The rest of the files are served but those 5 or 6 which the browser never receives a response for. Eventually I'll get a `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer` error (stack trace below) in the terminal. Additionally, if I enable the cache in my browser and attempt a few refreshes things will work fine, almost as if theres a limit to the number of files that can be served at once and once some files are cached in the browser the number of requested files falls below that limit.

When I do `python manage.py runserver`, however, I don't seem to have this problem at all with or without caching enabled.

Stack Trace:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52655)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 320, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 351, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/myuser/Path/To/Project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/myuser/Path/To/Project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

**Additional Notes/Observations**

- The problem also occurs when I run the tests headless.
- Installing Cypress did run into a hitch that required me to reinstall Electron and Cypress, clear the npm cache and delete the Cypress cache folder.
- It's also strange that the problem seems to be with the python environment and not Cypress itself since accessing the web server via my browser and not Cypress produces the same behaviour; so perhaps Cypress is just a red herring and some sort of shared dependency was changed/updated in the process.
- If I attempt to directly access one of the files that doesn't get served during a request, which is displayed as 'pending' in Chrome Developer's tools network tab, directly via a second tab it will succeed (but sometimes be lagged by several seconds).
- After closing the test server and attempting to run it again I will get an `[OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use]` error for up to a minute or two. Previously the server would relinquish the address/port immediately upon closing (or I'm assuming as such since I've never seen this before and had rapidly closed and re-ran tests to test fixture changes in the past).

**Things I've Tried**:

- Rebuilding my virtualenv from scratch
- Copying my old venv folder from a Time Machine backup from a time when things worked
- Reverting the version of Cypress back to what it was prior to the problem
- Looking into timeouts and connection limits of using `manage.py test` vs `manage.py runserver` (Didn't find anything).
- Toggling DEBUG mode and profiling on/off.
- Switching between Chrome and Chromium in Cypress
- Building new environments with different python versions (3.6.5, 3.6.7 and 3.6.8)
- Switching Django back to 2.2.2 from 2.2.3

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update**

Looking into this further it looks like the requests for the files that don't get a response never make it to the WSGIHandler form the Socket layer (or even if they make it to the socket layer, I'd assume they do though).

**Update 2**

I see the same behaviour with `manage.py runserver` if I include the `--nothreading` switch. I had a co-worker give it a test and he indeed saw the same behaviour with `manage.py runserver --nothreading` but `manage.py test test.to.run` still functioned fine for him.

Also removing the font references from the css/templates just results in a different set of 5 files that aren't served.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem for almost a year now, different macOS versions, different Django/Python versions, different VS Code/Python extension versions.... Did you happen to find a solution yet? This seems related btw: https://bugs.python.org/issue27682#msg348302

Comment: Unfortunately no. But I do have a few work arounds:

1) Turn the test server with while/sleep statement and then update your settings file to point to your test database.
2) For some reason rolling Cypress all the way back to 3.1.1 also seemed to allow the tests to run headless.